# Best way to minimize and package multiple JavaScript files in a web app?

Tags: javascript, web

I am dealing with some legacy web apps which are loading 70+ JavaScript files (libraries, core files and custom files). Only a handful of these files are "minimized" while most of them are not. All files are local and not coming from CDN. These web apps are deployed inside secured data centers (private clouds) and does not necessary have access to internet (I know it sounds funny, but most enterprise private clouds are like that).

What would be the best way to "minimize" all these files and keep them local? Is it possible to merge 70+ JS files into 1 large "minimized" JS file to save bandwidth/performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using something like: [minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify).

We have used it for quite some time. There may be other solutions also, but I am curious to hear from others as well.